# Initializing const member during construction

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I am struggling to initialize a class member which is const. I made an example that works in Coliru.

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A(int id)
    : id_(id)
    {}
    int getId() const { return id_; }
private:
    int id_;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(const std::vector<A>& vecA)
    : ids_(vecA.size())
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < vecA.size(); ++i)
        {
            ids_[i] = vecA[i].getId();
        }
    }
    
private:
    /*const*/ std::vector<int> ids_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vecA = { A(1), A(3), A(10) };
    
    return 0;
}
```

How is it possible to initialize **B.ids_** below if **ids_** is a *const* member?
In above piece of code I forced **B.ids_** to be *non-const* and it compiles fine:

```
 /*const*/ std::vector<int> ids_;
```

However if I make **ids_** const, above code obviously doesn't compile as

```
ids_[i] = vecA[i].getId();
```

is illegal. Is there any way (e.g. using lambda functions) to initialize **ids_** directly in B's initializer list?

Comment: It's usually best not to have `const` data members.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. The problem is that, unfortunately, I can't unconst it.

Comment: fwiw, browse a bit down in the answers on the duplciate to find an answer that shows how to encapsulate complicated initialization of const member in a function.

Comment: why you cannot "unconst" it?  It is private. Just don't provide any means to modify it from outside, then it is `const` for all practical purposes but without the complications that come with actually declaring it as `const`

Comment: @Mushtandoid I recommend that you argument to make it non-`const`. Constant member variables are a real pain. That said, you can use a helper function, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zooKoz)

Comment: @TedLyngmo that brings me the idea of a immediately invoked lambda expression. If I didn't miss it taths not on the dupe yet

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, that'd be really nice too. No idea if that's in the dupe. Here is [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/Tes4vY) though.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo. Example with the lambda function is quite nice.

Comment: @Mushtandoid You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks @largest_prime_is_463035818, making it unconsts is the easiest way, agree. I will have both options on the table :)